# How to convert different contrast parts of image to curve?

Tags: bezier-curves, image, baking, draw-mode

Suppose I have this image.
[image: Sample Map of India]

and I want to convert it into curve for this animation [Curve animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fN3WfMUckN8)

Watch from start to 0:03
I can do it by Bevel Factor in Blender.
But i Have to make the curve by "Draw Curve" Is there any simpler way. Please Tell.

Comment: You'd be better off finding a vector version of this image in, say, SVG file format or something. Blender doesn't have a tracer as far as I know, maybe try Inkscape, but quality will be sub par

Comment: You need image tracer - try your luck here: https://vectormagic.com/. Blender can import SVG for further animating.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to this [website](http://www.d-maps.com/m/asia/india/inde/inde29.svg)

Right click on the image and click Save page as (The download file will be in svg format)

**Import File**

File -> Import -> SVG (If svg is not enable, enable from the addon)

Now u need little cleanup.

Delete the unwanted parts (scale,etc)

Go to edit mode and select the outer edge and delete vertices

Now you have a clean India Map with the curve

[image]

If you need to download separate state download [here](https://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/?map=india). Color the different state and place it.

**How to Bevel**

Go to the curve tab

Change the shape from 2D to 3D

Add a curve circle.

Select the Map curve and in the bevel object select the circle.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I need curves for bevel factor(only applicable when it is an open curve(start and ending vertices are joined)

Comment: @ComputerGuy yes with this you can bevel it. I have edited the answer

Comment: Thanks For your post. But how did you produce svg file from jpeg/png

Comment: @ComputerGuy If u want any jpeg and png to turn into svg then the comment was given above by Duarte & Jerryno to have a vector software or go online to convert. As i found a good svg of India Map so have given all the reference and link in my answer.